# How to bring the name of the checkbox/radiobutton into the function

Tags: c#, wpf

I using WPF and C# to build my application. Inside my application, i have quite lots of check boxes. Since i have lots of check boxes, there will be **a LOTS** of if checkbox.isChecked = true then do something....So, i need to create a function for the event whenever the check boxes is checked in order to make sure my coding is not flooded with the checkbox.isChecked.

```
public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CheckTrueFlase(checkboxA);
        CheckTrueFlase(checkboxB);
        CheckTrueFlase(checkboxC);
        CheckTrueFlase(checkboxD);
    }
```

The function will be something like:

```
private string CheckTrueFalse(/*What parameter i should write in this area?*/) 
{
   string x;

   if(checkbox.isChecked == true)
     x = "correct";
   else if (checkbox.isChecked == false)
     x = "wrong";

   return x;
 }
```

Comment: What do you wan to write in /*how to write in this area?*/? could you elaborate more

Comment: @Cuong Le :It mean what parameter i should put inside the parathesis....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do the trick.

```
private string CheckTrueFalse(System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox checkbox) 
{
    string x;

    if (checkbox.isChecked)
        x = "correct";
    else
        x = "wrong";

    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can register the event of all checkboxs(form.controls) to the same method and sending the sender (converted to checkbox) to your method. I dont know wpf but I guess it is similar to winforms, this is an answer for winforms.